# How to list all files in directory excluding any that start with a dot?

Tags: terminal

I'm currently using the command

```
find /Volumes/DriveName > driveName.txt
```

to create a file listing of all files that are on the drive.

How could I modify my command (or what would be a better command) to have the list not include any dot files, for example ._Filename or .DSstore?

I'm not looking for software like CDFinder etcetera to keep a searchable database. I need a text output that contains all the files on the disk, as well as their relative locations to each other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To exclude files and directories add an exclusion pattern to the find command (see `info find` for more):

```
find /Volumes/DriveName -not -path '*/.*' > driveName.txt
```

Comment: You could also just use `ls -R /Volumes/DriveName > driveName.txt` depending on the output format you want.

Comment: For some reason using the -not -name is still returning results like:/Volumes/GLYPH_500//.fseventsd/000000000093d655
/Volumes/GLYPH_500//.fseventsd/fseventsd-uuid
/Volumes/GLYPH_500//.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1

Comment: Also, ls -l is returning results like: /Volumes/GLYPH_500//.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1/Stores/550F2517-530C-4ECB-98BA-63799078A359:
0.indexArrays
0.indexCompactDirectory

Comment: This is because `-name` only checks the filename, to match against the whole path replace `-name` with `-path` and the pattern with `'*/.*'`.

Comment: You are right! That totally fixed it. Could you edit your response to include that - and I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't remotely Mac-specific, but you can pipe your output through `grep`. More particularly, the `-v` option will exclude lines that match the pattern you are looking for (in your case, filenames beginning with a `.`).

So instead of

```
find /Volumes/DriveName > driveName.txt
```

you can enter

```
find /Volumes/DriveName | grep -v '\/\.' > driveName.txt
```

Comment: this one gets rid of all items .Spotlight listings etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to recommend `tree` as an alternative, but I realized it's not installed by default on OS X. However if you don't mind following some [straightforward instructions to compile it yourself](http://shaunchapman.me/post/329270449/how-to-install-the-tree-command-on-mac-os-x), it might be a useful tool for your purposes. It takes any directory and gives you a nice ASCII based tree of all the subfolders and files therein (and by default it omits hidden/dot files).

Sample output:

```
~$ tree test
test
├── alpha
│   ├── testA
│   ├── testB
│   └── testC
├── num
│   ├── test1
│   ├── test2
│   └── test3
├── test X
├── test Y
└── test Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListAllFiles](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/listallfiles/id539459130?mt=12) from the App Store.

Comment: Well, giving that you are promoting your own product here, I would have expected a bit more text and not just a link.